# Plotting values on an Argand diagram,

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I am attempting to plot the following functions on an Argand diagram.

$|z + 4 − 8i| = 15$,

$z^2 + \bar z^2 = 1$

$\operatorname{Re}(z^2)=1$

My attempt for: $z^2 + \bar z^2 = 1$

$(x+iy)^2+(x-iy)^2=1$, this gives $x^2 - y^2 = \frac 1 2 $ which I can plot if this is correct.

My attempt for: $\operatorname{Re}(z^2)=1$

$(z^2)=x^2-y^2 +2ixy $, therefore $Re(z^2)=x^2-y^2=1$

This again is simple to plot if my attempt is correct.

My attempt for: $|z + 4 − 8i| = 15$

$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$z=x+iy$, therefore $|x+iy+4-8i|=15$

$\sqrt{(x+4)^2+(y-8)^2}=15$

$x^2+8x+y^2-16y=145$

I am not really sure if this is correct. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the complex-variable equation

$$|z + 4 − 8i| = 15$$

is the standard form of a circle in the complex plane, which has the center at $-4+8i$ and the radius $15$. The corresponding $xy$-equation is then,

$$(x+4)^2+(y-8)^2 = 15^2$$

which is equivalent to $x^2+8x+y^2-16y=145$.

Comment: @GavinK14 - you're welcome